# serverless deployment error - Code storage limit exceeded

Tags: serverless-framework

Deployment of my serverless project has started returning the following error

> An error occurred while provisioning your stack... [lambda name][GUID] - Code storage limit exceeded..

I've tried deleting zip packages thinking there a limit to how many upload packages can be stored in the S3 bucket, but no luck.

As mentioned by Trent below, I've looked at the deployment limits, but with a compressed packaged of 2.1MB (8MB uncompressed) I can't see what limits I would be exceeding.

Any suggestions on what might be causing this.

**(My) Solution:**

I was hoping to get a better understanding of the underlying problem, and was hoping to do this as a last resort. But it appears by deleting the stack from cloudformation and redeploying the serverless project the problem has fixed itself.

Comment: I have the same problem, I am tried to deploy only hello world function. Is it any other solution.

Answer (score 7):

For anybody else finding this through google, hope this helps.

**What is causing it?**

AWS has a limit of 75GB on the size of all the deployment packages that can be uploaded per region. This includes all of your Lambda functions and all their historical versions combined in a given region.

The error could happen if you have a large number of Lambda functions that have been deployed many times. Each deployment creates a version and this can add up over time.

**Solution 1**

If you do not need to version your Lambda functions, you can turn off Lambda versioning by setting it in your serverless.yml.

```
provider:
  name: aws
  versionFunctions: false
```

**Solution 2**

Alternatively, you can manually remove older Lambda versions. You can use the serverless-prune-plugin to automate the process for you. The plugin can be used to do a one-time clean up, or can be configured in your serverless.yml to auto prune older Lambda versions after each deployment.

Here's more details about this error - https://seed.run/docs/serverless-errors/code-storage-limit-exceeded

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

> Every Lambda function is allocated with a fixed amount of specific resources regardless of the memory allocation, and each function is allocated with a fixed amount of code storage per function and per account.

Lambdas have invocation limits, but also *deployment* limits, which is what your problem is. Look through the limits and work out which one has been breached.

Comment: Thanks Trent. The serverless package zipped is 2.1MB and uncompressed 8.1MB. This doesn't seem to exceed any of the deployment limits.

What seems strange is that deployment was fine using the "sls deploy" command, small one line change to the code followed by a redeploy and all of a sudden this error message is occuring.

Comment: In that case, you have too many previous versions of your lambdas and need to clear them out.

Comment: Same problem with create new serverless application, for different account working fine for me.

Comment: What was problem here? Did you delete old packages?

Answer (score 0):

Lambda creates a version of your functions on each deployment, so frequent deploys can cause storage problems. Your solution is correct, however you can also remove other unused versions of your functions by writing a simple script.

First, you would like to get the versions of your functions

```
`const params = {
  FunctionName: 'functionName'
};
lambda.listVersionsByFunction(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
  else     console.log(data);
});`
```

then decide which ones you want to delete

```
`const params2 = {
  FunctionName: 'functionName',
  Qualifier: '1' //version of your function you want to delete
};
lambda.deleteFunction(params2, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
  else     console.log(data);
});`
```